# Oracle error when inserting into table using SELECT in C#

Tags: c#, sql-insert, oracle12c

I am trying to insert into a table using SELECT and then retrieve the ID of inserted record.

When I copy/paste the query, minus its ID retrieval part, into SQL Developer it works fine. So there is something wrong with ID retrieval part and I can't see the issue.

This is what i am using in SQL developer and it inserts:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (TABLE1_ID,COL1, COL2, ..., COLn) 
SELECT 0, COL1, COL2, ..., COLn, 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE SOME_ID = 16;
```

Same query in C#, with ID retrieval part:

```
int iOutID = -1;

string sQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (TABLE1_ID,COL1, COL2, ..., COLn) " + 
"SELECT 0, COL1, COL2, ..., COLn, " +
"FROM TABLE2 " +
"WHERE SOME_ID = 16 " +
"RETURNING TABLE1_ID INTO :OutID";

dbContext.Open();
List<OracleParameter> spParams = new List<OracleParameter>();
OracleParameter outParam = new OracleParameter("OutID", OracleDbType.Decimal, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
spParams.Add(outParam);
dbContext.ExecuteOraNonQuery(sQuery, spParams, ref iOutID);
iOutID= int.Parse(outParam.Value.ToString());
```

It throws an exception

```
"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".
```

**Update**

Modified query, as suggested, to use the top row:

```
string sQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (TABLE1_ID,COL1, COL2, ..., COLn) " + 
"SELECT 0, COL1, COL2, ..., COLn FROM ("
"SELECT 0, COL1, COL2, ..., COLn, " +
"FROM TABLE2 " +
"WHERE SOME_ID = 16 " +
"ORDER BY Some_Date DESC) " +
"WHERE ROWNUM = 1 " +
"RETURNING TABLE1_ID INTO :OutID";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your first example has the possibility of inserting multiple rows.

This becomes an error as soon as you say you just want a single id returned - Oracle is helpfully preventing you from writing buggy SQL.

Does adding `ROWNUM = 1` to the WHERE clause help?

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and post back

Comment: Well, if this *is* an error, won't result in "SQL command not properly ended".

Comment: Sorry, didn't help.

Comment: "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" means there is a syntax error in the sql - specifically it hints that the last bit "RETURNING TABLE1_ID INTO :OutID" is not allowed in this context - it is allowed when you insert a single row using VALUES, but not when there's a possibility that the insert could insert multiple rows

Comment: You need to re-write so that it understands that you are only inserting a single row

Comment: I modified it, as suggested by Stewart, by adding an outer select and using "where rownum=1", still get the same error. I modified the question to reflect the change, maybe I messed up there too!